# Page with some post value id showing page not found

Tags: customization, page-template

I have customized the template and sending some value using POST method to each custom page. All custom page is working good except the last custom page where I need to insert the data with mail send option. It is working good when I browse the page but not with POST value.

I am using phpmailer for mail send.

/**
 * Template Name:  Download Page
 **/
session_start(); 
get_header();
/*

*/

    include 'connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['download'])){
      $psize  = $_SESSION['psize'];
      $size   = $_SESSION['size'];
      $name   = $_POST['name'];
      $mobile = $_POST['mobilephone'];
      $email_id= $_POST['emailid'];
      $size     = $_SESSION['size'];
      $ctprice  = $_POST['ctprice'];
      $appl =  $_POST['appl'];
      $appln  = $_POST['appln'];
      $image = stripslashes($_POST['image']);
      $filenameID = date('mdYHis') . mt_rand(6, 10);
      $total_sub1 = $size + $ctprice;

    //  echo $total_sub1."
";

      $total_sub2 =0;

      foreach($_POST['appl'] as $field)
      {
          if($field == '')
          {
              echo "error - doesn't have a value";
          } else {

            $total_sub2+=$field;
          }    
      }

      $total = $total_sub1 + $total_sub2;
      //  echo $total."
";
      for ($i = 0; $i 
          
            
              '. $appln[$i].'
               INR '. $appl[$i].'
            
          
          ';
          //echo $Appliance;
      }
}
    $filename = date('mdYHis');

    require_once "PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php";

    //PHPMailer Object
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

    //From email address and name
    $mail->From = "no_reply@example.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Customized Kitchen";

    //To address and name
    $mail->addAddress($email_id, "Recepient Name");
    $mail->addAddress($email_id); //Recipient name is optional

    //Address to which recipient will reply
    $mail->addReplyTo("no_reply@example.com", "Reply");

    //CC and BCC
    //$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
    //$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

    //Send HTML or Plain Text email
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = 'Custom Kitchen';
    $mail->Body = 'Content';
    //$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

      if(!$mail->send()) 
      {
         // echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
          echo "Message has been failed";
          echo '

#### Somthing went wrong. Your customization is not Saved.

For customisation Visit here -> Customize

';
      } 
      else 
      {
          $sql = "INSERT INTO `enquiry`(`name`, `email`, `mobile`, `layout`,`fileID` ,`fileHTML`, `cost`, `total`) VALUES ('$name','$email_id','$mobile','$layout','$filenameID','$image','$total_sub1','$total')";
         // echo $sql;
            $result = $connect->query($sql);

            if($result){

               $msg = "success";
               echo "Message has been sent successfully";
            } else {
               $msg = "failed";
               echo "

Please Try Again

";          

            }        
      }
    }
/*
    
    
    
    
          

            
*/

      if(isset($_GET['file'])){
          $file=$_GET['file'];
         // echo $file;
          $sql_file = "SELECT `fileHTML` FROM `enquiry` WHERE `fileId`='$file'";
        //  echo $sql_file;
          $res_file = $connect->query($sql_file);
          if ($res_file->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
              while($row_file = $res_file->fetch_assoc()){

            //    
                  
             /*   
             //   
              //   Download
             */

              }
          }
      }

    /*/

*/
get_footer();

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue. The issue was in variable $name and $name is reserved in wordpress. So I have changed it to $fname. And now it is working fine.